# How to change navigator font size on Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode7, xcode12

Is there any way to change the font size of the navigator panel in xcode? I've managed to change the font size in the edit window with preference->font & color, but that does not change the font size of the navigator.

Answer (score 15):

### For Xcode 12 & Above

[image]
Its default value is matched the system's Resolution. (check my early answer).

---

##### How to change system system's Resolution on macOS?

##### Solution before 2020 - **AKA My Early Answer**

Only way to change Resolution is changing system preferences for now. System preferences > Displays > Change resolution option from "Default for display" to "Scaled" and choose as you wish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is this [MMNavigatorFont plugin](https://github.com/adad184/MMNavigatorFont) that should do the job, you have to install it through [Alcatraz](http://alcatraz.io)

Comment: Unfortunately plugins are not supported by Xcode 8 and above. From Alcatraz main page: Please note that plugins are no longer supported since Xcode 8.
Alcatraz is available for Xcode 7 only. See issue #475 for more information.