# Xcode 8 project navigator font size

Tags: xcode8, font-size, macos-sierra, project-navigator

I have updated to MacOS 10.12.4 Sierra and Xcode 8.3.2 but now going blind because the Xcode project navigator font size is so small.  Is there a way to increase the navigator font size?  We used to be allowed to do this with a plugin such as MMNavigatorFont but no longer.

Comment: You can check out this answer for one option:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939207/xcode7-change-navigator-font-size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939207/xcode7-change-navigator-font-size)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change navigator font size on Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939207/how-to-change-navigator-font-size-on-xcode)